# Take retina screenshots with XCode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm trying to use XCode 7 to take screenshots of all the iPhone models before submitting to the App Store. I've seen other posts say that "retina" devices are available under the Hardware menu item in the Simulator app. However, I do not see any retina devices in that menu and when I take screenshots, they are not at the correct resolutions. Does anyone know how to use XCode 7 and the Simulator to take App Store ready screenshots?

Comment: Every simulated device except the iPad 2 is retina (at least any device supported with Xcode 7). Just make sure you have the Simulator window at 100% scale before taking the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

As discused in the [Simulator Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide) (Using the Debugging Tools in Simulator section):

> **Optimize Rendering for Window Scale**
>   Selecting this option improves the
>   rendering speed of the screen for scaled simulated devices. The option
>   is useful for large devices such as iPad Pro. Screen shots are saved
>   at the scaled resolution when this option is active. To save a full
>   resolution screenshot, temporarily disable this option.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the simulator scale is at 100%: Window > Scale > 100%